# Node.js : Stream file with @fastify/multipart to AWS S3 throw the error "A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented"

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, stream, fastify, fastify-multipart

I have a fastify app with a route `/api/upload` where I upload an image, using the `@fastify/multipart` npm package.

The handler for this route basically use the stream of the file to upload directly to an AWS S3 bucket.

The following is the implementation I tried :

```js
import { PutObjectCommand, S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

export const uploadImage = async (req, res) => {
    /* get the uploaded file data */
    const data = await req.file();

    /* init the S3 client */
    const S3 = new S3Client({
        region: 'your-region',
        credentials: {
            accessKeyId: 'your-access-key',
            secretAccessKey: 'your-secret-key'
        }
    });

    /* create the command to add a new object to the S3 bucket */
    const command = new PutObjectCommand({
        Bucket: 'your-bucket-name',
        Key: 'fileName.jpg',
        Body: data.file /* THIS IS WHERE I GIVE THE FILE STREAM */
    });

    /* send the command */
    await S3.send(command);

    return res.code(200).send({
        status: 'success'
    });
};
```

When this handler is executed, an error is throw with the following :

```js
{
    "status": "error",
    "typeCode": "SERVER_ERROR",
    "message": "A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented",
    "error": {
        "name": "NotImplemented",
        "$fault": "client",
        "$metadata": {
            "httpStatusCode": 501,
            "requestId": "5TCZZ4KZC5PQW2SY",
            "extendedRequestId": "vzS1IWfX0thCd1PO30SnP1g1cBd0uWrHewCMLtvpHe+Ut2onCv27QgK2JauxwIeT7tTGmBGkSAo=",
            "attempts": 1,
            "totalRetryDelay": 0
        },
        "Code": "NotImplemented",
        "Header": "Transfer-Encoding",
        "RequestId": "5TCZZ4KZC5PQW2SY",
        "HostId": "vzS1IWfX0thCd1PO30SnP1g1cBd0uWrHewCMLtvpHe+Ut2onCv27QgK2JauxwIeT7tTGmBGkSAo=",
        "message": "A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented",
        "HTTPCode": 500,
        "status": "error",
        "typeCode": "SERVER_ERROR"
    }
}
```

I don't understand why, I've looked all over the internet, but can't find the solution.

I tried uploading the same file to S3 by reading it as a stream with the native node.js module like this :

```js
import fs from 'node:fs';
import { PutObjectCommand, S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

export const uploadImage = async (req, res) => {
    /* read directly the file from disk */
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream('path-to-file');

    /* init the S3 client */
    const S3 = new S3Client({
        region: 'your-region',
        credentials: {
            accessKeyId: 'your-access-key',
            secretAccessKey: 'your-secret-key'
        }
    });

    /* create the command to add a new object to the S3 bucket */
    const command = new PutObjectCommand({
        Bucket: 'your-bucket-name',
        Key: 'fileName.jpg',
        Body: readStream /* THIS WORKS */
    });

    /* send the command */
    await S3.send(command);

    return res.code(200).send({
        status: 'success'
    });
};
```

And it works as expected.

I would really need some help, please.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved my issue.

With this answer from stack overflow :
[Upgrade aws-sdk to version 3 - streaming S3 upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69841549/upgrade-aws-sdk-to-version-3-streaming-s3-upload)

It seems like it's a known bug.

What I did instead of the suggested answer is just :

```js
import { Upload } from '@aws-sdk/lib-storage';
import { S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

export const uploadImage = async (req, res) => {
    /* get the uploaded file data */
    const data = await req.file();

    /* init the S3 client */
    const S3 = new S3Client({
        region: 'your-region',
        credentials: {
            accessKeyId: 'your-access-key',
            secretAccessKey: 'your-secret-key'
        }
    });

    const upload = new Upload({
        client: S3,
        params: {
            Bucket: 'your-bucket-name',
            Key: 'fileName.jpg',
            Body: data.file,
            ContentType: 'text/plain'
        },
    });

    await upload.done();

    return res.code(200).send({
        status: 'success'
    });
};
```